# Vaadin FormLayout as Stateful JEE bean

Tags: jakarta-ee, vaadin

I'm trying to make a JEE version of the 'Customer' tutorial application (https://github.com/vaadin/tutorial).

I try to convert the 'CustomerForm' (https://github.com/vaadin/tutorial/blob/master/src/main/java/my/vaadin/app/CustomerForm.java) to a stateful session bean. I've moved the content of the constructor to a function annotated with @PostConstruct and added the @Stateful to the class.

When accessing the page that uses the form I get the following error (NOTE: in the log below PatientForm is actually the CustomerForm)

> Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: Class
>   org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections can not access a member of
>   class com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector with modifiers
>   "protected"
>           at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:437)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:127)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:67)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
>           at com.tekliko.forensic.view.PatientForm$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.isThis(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.equals(AbstractClientConnector.java:1075)
>           at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.isOrHasAncestor(AbstractComponent.java:1377)
>           at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponentContainer.addComponent(AbstractComponentContainer.java:168)
>           at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractOrderedLayout.addComponent(AbstractOrderedLayout.java:95)
>           at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponentContainer.addComponents(AbstractComponentContainer.java:57)
>           at com.vaadin.ui.HorizontalLayout.(HorizontalLayout.java:50)
>           at com.tekliko.forensic.view.PatientListView.initComponent(PatientListView.java:58)
>           ... 78 more

The @Stateful annotation is causing the problem. If I remove the annotation, surprisingly, injection of the CustomerForm in the view works and injection of the persistence unit in CustomerForm works also (injected using @PersistenceContext). Nevertheless I cannot call the EntityManager 'merge' function probably because the bean is not a proper JEE bean.

> 0:39:53,306 SEVERE [com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler] (default
>   task-24) : javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException:
>   WFLYJPA0060: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either
>   use a transaction or extended persistence context)

Comment: Any particular reason you're trying to save the _form_ and not the associated _customer_ data?

Comment: Are you using [Vaadin CDI](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/vaadin-cdi)?

Comment: @Morfic I'm trying to save the customer data of course

Comment: @pirho yes the 'Customer' tutorial application uses CDI

Comment: Vaadin have reference applications for both JEE and Spring, have a look at those. Also, you do not want to save the form as a stateful session bean. For controlling the lifecycle of forms, there are annotations for that, I think you wlll find them in Vaadin CDI-integration. And for storing the actual data you would use an @Entity.